# Unital primitive ring with its center is not a field

Tags: ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra

I need to find a unital and primitive ring R such that center of R is not a field, can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to mathstack exchange. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can help.  Google “center of a primitive ring” and read the results.  You’re welcome!

Comment: Thank you :) i couldnt find but i will look at again